# Why is numpy too slow when extracting data from CDF files using pycdf?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, hstack

I would like to extract a variable "time" from cdf file named "filename.cdf". For this I used the following code:

```
import numpy as np 
from spacepy import pycdf 

data = pycdf.CDF('filename.cdf')
e1 = np.array(data['time']);
e2 = np.hstack([time, e1]) if time.size else e1
```

The size of variable "time" is 5529600. It takes a hell lot of time when I execute `e1` and `e2`.

What is the correct method to work with such huge datasets?

Comment: Are you low on free memory? That could explain a slow array allocation. Otherwise I advise specifiying the dtype of the array to avoid the cost of having it inferred: `e1 = np.array(data['time'], dtype=np.float32);` for instance

Comment: Great!! That worked!! It took time, but lesser than the previous one!

The other one is still running.... :(

Comment: Okay, let's move it into an answer for visibility

Comment: What is `time.size`? There is no variable called `time` in your code.

Comment: There were two codes running side by side.
1) `e1 = np.array(data['time'])` 
`e2 = np.hstack([time, e1]) if time.size else e1`

2)' e1 = np.array(data['time'], dtype=np.float32)'

When I checked, it was actually code 1 that ran perfectly fine, while code 2 showed an error. Saying np.float cannot take time.time(). It took about 288 seconds for 1st code to run

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not because you are low on memory, which could explain a slow array allocation. I advise specifiying the dtype of the array to avoid the cost of having it inferred:

```py
e1 = np.array(data['time'], dtype=np.float32);
```

or

```py
e1 = np.array(data['time'], dtype=np.int64);
```

depending on the numerical type you wish for.